# Custom string from TextBox in webrequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

i am trying to send a HttpWebRequest with the following body :

`string body = "{\"prompt\": \"MyText\",\"n\": 2,\"size\": \"256x256\",\"response_format\":\"b64_json\"}";`

the request works perfectly with this body, but everytime i try to change "MyText" with a text from textbox, i get an error 400 from server.

i tried this (return error 400):
`string  body = "{\"prompt\":" +textBox1.Text+",\"n\": 2,\"size\": \"256x256\",\"response_format\":\"b64_json\"}";`

any ideas ?

Comment: Don't make the JSON for the request body manually. Use library such as *System.Text.Json* or *Newtonsoft.Json* to generate the JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not recommended to build your JSON manually as you will highly expose to syntax errors due to missing/extra quotes, braces, etc especially when dealing with complex objects/arrays.

Using the libraries such as *System.Text.Json* or *Newtonsoft.Json* for the JSON serialization. This is safer and easier compared to building it manually.

```cs
using System.Text.Json;

var obj = new
    {
        prompt = textBox1.Text,
        n = 2,
        size = "256x256",
        response_format = "b64_json"
    };
        
string body = JsonSerializer.Serialize(obj);
```

```cs
using Newtonsoft.Json;
        
string body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```